# AppleScript : get all the values of a specified key in a plist file

Tags: applescript, plist

I'm looking for a way to get ALL the values for a specified key in a plist file.
Indeed, I want to go through the plist file and every time I read the specified key, I put the value in an array for example.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to access the values with sed.  Assuming:

[image]

```
set keyValues to paragraphs of (do shell script "sed -En '/CFBundleIconFile/ {
n
s/.*>([^<]+).*/\\1/
p
}' < " & quoted form of "/Users/John/Desktop/Info.plist")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you fully, but here's an example on how to read all the IODisplayLocation values from the windowserver preferences and create an applescript array.

```
set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
set theItems to (do shell script "defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver | grep IODisplayLocation | awk '{print $3}'")
set itemList to (every text item of theItems) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
display dialog item 4 of itemList
```